# angularjs ui-router url match

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular app with the following path:

http://localhost:8080/Map#/main

And I configured `$stateProvider` as following.

```
$stateProvider.state('index',
  {
    url:'/main',
    views: {
      'main': {
        controller:'xxCtrl',
        tempateUrl:'xxTemplate'
      }
    }
  })
```

However, the ui-view would not load the template.

//Update:
I used html5mode before and it works fine. However, as html5mode is not supported in IE9. It stopped working after I turned off for html5mode. And I'm using Asp.Net as backend.

It seems like it does not find a match somehow?

Anyone can help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your markup as well

Comment: The template will work only if a GET to `http://localhost:8080/xxTemplate` returns a HTML page. Is that the case?

Comment: the template and controller is good as far as I can see. The only concern is for the url matching. I was using html5mode, but we need to support IE9. then I turned off html5mode and it stopped working. I'm using ASP.Net as backend.